# this is the error cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code i am facing

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, yolo

Actually I want to write a code for object detection by using Yolov4 tiny and open cv
but i am getting that error again and again so anyone knows about the solution for this problem

My Python version is 3.10.9, and the TensorFlow version that I'm installing is 2.12.0. Every time I run my code, it shows that my package can't apply to my python. I've tried Chat GPT and every source on the internet, but I still can't solve it. What can I do?

This is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load Yolo
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("dnn_model/yolov4-tiny.weights","dnn_model/yolov4-tiny.cfg")
classes = []
with open("dnn_model/classes.txt", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

# Loading image
img = cv2.imread("peic.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
height, width, channels = img.shape

# Detecting objects
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)

net.setInput(blob)
outs = net.forward(output_layers)

# Showing informations on the screen
class_ids = []
confidences = []
boxes = []
for out in outs:
    for detection in out:
        scores = detection[5:]
        class_id = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[class_id]
        if confidence > 0.5:
            # Object detected
            center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
            center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
            w = int(detection[2] * width)
            h = int(detection[3] * height)

            # Rectangle coordinates
            x = int(center_x - w / 2)
            y = int(center_y - h / 2)

            boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            class_ids.append(class_id)

indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)
print(indexes)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
for i in range(len(boxes)):
    if i in indexes:
        x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
        label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        color = colors[i]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 3, color, 3)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I want to solve this problem

```
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```